# Buffered Reader reads only first line in Text file?

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

[image: Output Looks Like]

here i am trying to use Buffered reader to read text file and create table in database, but Buffered reader reads only First Name from my text file. May i know What is wrong in my code... It WORKS Fine In MySQL , but in SQL Server it reads only first name.

Text File: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=vrQs9

Whole Code :

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Stackq extends AbstractTableModel {

Vector<String> data;
Vector columns;

public Stackq() {






    String line;
    data = new Vector<String>();
    columns = new Vector();
    int count = 0;


    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:/joy/text/registration.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), "\t");
        while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
            columns.addElement(st1.nextToken());
            count++;
        }
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                } else {
                    data.addElement("");
                }
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    data.setElementAt((String) value, col);
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    //if (4 == col){

    return true;
}
//else {
// return false;
// }
//}

//public void insertData(Object[] values){
// data.add(new Vector());
//for(int i =0; i<values.length; i++){
//((Vector) data.get(data.size()-1)).add(values[i]);
//}
//fireTableDataChanged();
// }
public void removeRow(int row) {
    data.removeElementAt(row);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size() / getColumnCount();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return columns.size();
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return (String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount())
            + columnIndex);
}

public String getColumnName(int i) {
    return (String) columns.get(i);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {


    Stackq model = new Stackq();

    JTable table = new JTable();

    table.setModel(model);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(scrollpane);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel, "Center");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    StringBuffer sbTableData = new StringBuffer();
    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            sbTableData.append(table.getValueAt(row, column)).append("\t");
        }
        sbTableData.append("\n");

    }
    System.out.println(sbTableData);

    try {

    PrintWriter f = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/joy/text/registration6.txt", true)));

        //f.println(sbTableData+"\t"+"n");

        f.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String readstr1 = null;

    int row = table.getRowCount();

    int column = table.getColumnCount();

    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {

  //System.out.println(table.getValueAt(j, i));
            readstr1 = (String) table.getValueAt(j, i);
 //System.out.println(readstr);

        }

    }

    try {
        // FILE READ AND TABLE CREATE
        String tname = "example11199";
        String dbname = "DB";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=SOFTWARE\joy;databaseName=DB;integratedSecurity=true;");
        java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        // stmt=conn.createStatement();
     //System.out.println("connect");
     //System.out.println(readstr1);
        FileInputStream fstr = new FileInputStream("D:/joy/text/registration6.txt");
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream inn = new DataInputStream(fstr);
        BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inn));

        String readstr;
        java.sql.DatabaseMetaData dmd = conn.getMetaData();
        while ((readstr = brr.readLine()) != null) //DatabaseMetaData dmd = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
        //while(readstr!=null)
        {
            ResultSet rs = dmd.getTables(null, "DB", "example11199", null);
            //set not null column
            if (String.valueOf(readstr).contains("NO")) {
                readstr = readstr.replaceAll("NO", "not null");
            } else if (String.valueOf(readstr).contains("YES")) {
                readstr = readstr.replaceAll("YES", "");
            }
            if (String.valueOf(readstr).contains("PRIMARY")) {
                readstr = readstr.replaceFirst("PRIMARY", "primary key");
            }
            System.out.println("replace string " + readstr);

            int k = 1;
            if (!rs.next()) {
                stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + tname + "(" + readstr + ")");

            } else {
                //System.out.println(readstr);
                stmt.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE " + tname + " ADD(" + readstr + ")");
                System.out.println("altered");

            }

        }
        brr.close();
        inn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    }
    }
```

EDITED, Now all contents of text file  gets printed but it gives null here at last : System.out.println("replace string " + readstr); so i am unalble to create table with null value.
  Thank You.

Comment: Stopped reading after I saw that horrible code formatting... Fix it, and I'll try to understand what's going on...

Comment: Looks like you were writing in Notepad!!

Comment: @tim What IDE are you using?

Comment: @jlordo hi, sorry, i have edited the code, and i am using NetBeans

Comment: @tim: I am pretty sure NetBeans has some kind of shortcut to autoformat the code. Find and use it. You changed a bit, but it's still bad. You can then copy/paste your formatted code into the editor here.

Comment: Maybe if you wrap your exception and throw it as a RuntimeException you will be able to see what you are doing wrong the file reading code without db access reads the full file without any problems

Comment: @ExtremeCoders edlin?

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file.  You don't need it so please remove it.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, i have removed it and did it this way: FileInputStream fstr = new FileInputStream("D:/joy/text/registration6.txt");
BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstr));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-creating the table you read one line.  I assume this only works once, so it is only reading the first line.

You appear to have a jumble of text passing and altering a table so that only the file line is read before you attempt to create the table.  I suspect you want to read the whole file before you attempt to alter/create the table.

BTW Having formatting all over the place is likely to make checking your code much harder.  I suggest you use the formatter in your IDE and you should be able to see how your code will loop.

Comment: hi , as you said i have formatted the code using ALT+SHIFT+F Format Code in NetBeans, and provided the whole code in the post, may i know what is wrong now

Comment: Read the first two paragraphs again.  You can always ask me a question about my answer if you don't understand it.

Comment: actually i am new to Java and i didnt understand what you said, can you give me a example of were to change

Comment: Do all the file reading before to you attempt to alter the database.  Don't mix them up as you will just confuse yourself.

Comment: yes you are right i want to read the whole file before you attempt to alter/create the table, any example how to do it ?

Comment: I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be.  It is very simple.  All your code for reading the file should appear first, there should be no code for using the database in this portion of your code.  Only then should you attempt to access the database and in this portion of the code you should not be attempting to read the file. i.e. you put all the reading code before all the database code.

Comment: hi as you said when i put all reading code before all the database code, it works but table is not created in database

Comment: I would make sure you are not throwing an exception you are ignoring.  I suggest you display the exception caught at the end of the try/catch block.  I would also make sure you are committing your changes and closing off your database resources correctly.

Comment: this is what i got when i Printed the try{} block Exception com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'.

Comment: So you are generating an SQL statement which contains a `null` value.  I suggest to printout your SQL statement before you run it to check it is correct.  BTW: This is a good example of why you shouldn't ignore your errors. ;)

Comment: SQL statement  Prints :SQLServerStatement:2

Comment: Actually the replace String is null i guess , so table is not created, OP Looks this way : replace string FirstName        VARCHAR(20)        not null                                
replace string LastName        VARCHAR(20)        not null                                
replace string Gender        VARCHAR(20)        not null                                
...                                       
replace string  // here its null        
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'.

Comment: I forgot `null` is a valid keyword in SQL.  In any case the SQL you are trying to execute is not valid and this is what you should be looking at and correcting.

Comment: What would be the valid SQL in my code ? Could you give an example of it.

Comment: I think you will have to workout the valid SQL code yourself as that doesn't really have anything to do with Java.  You can search for valid examples of SQL.

Comment: finally i have to create the table alone and as you said i will give a try on that and let you know how the code works, i thank you so much for helping and guiding me .... Looking Forward to chat with you in future

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ((readstr = brr.readLine()) != null) //DatabaseMetaData dmd = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
    //while(readstr!=null)
    {
        ResultSet rs = dmd.getTables(null, "DB", "example11199", null);
        //set not null column
        if (String.valueOf(readstr).contains("NO")) {
            readstr = readstr.replaceAll("NO", "not null");
        } else if (String.valueOf(readstr).contains("YES")) {
            readstr = readstr.replaceAll("YES", "");
        }else if (String.valueOf(readstr).contains("PRIMARY")) {
            readstr = readstr.replaceFirst("PRIMARY", "primary key");
        }
        System.out.println("replace string " + readstr);
```

Try to fix the last if statement  Check it again and it will Work.